# QLineEdit thousand separator

Tags: c++, qt

With a QLineEdit is it possible to display the thousand separator of a number while user enter it

Which is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect a slot to the `void QLineEdit::textEdited ( const QString & text )` signal of your `QLineEdit` and add some space/separator in the edited string via the `setText()` method. It should work since `textEdit` won't be emit-ed again.

The Qt doc says :

> Unlike textChanged(), this signal (textEdited) is
>   not emitted when the text is changed
>   programmatically, for example, by
>   calling setText().

You can take advantage of this situation to check if the string entered by the user is actually a number and correct it if needed.